# C++ Containers of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have been pondering an issue today and it's difficult to find the answer on google.

I'm trying to understand the STL container behaviour when dealing with pointers to both objects allocated on the heap, and on the stack.

So, start with objects, no pointers ... imagine I have ...

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int myInt = 5;
    myVec.push_back(myInt);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

My understanding is that the pop_back() method will ensure the integers contained in the vector are deleted, not just removed from the container. So if this ran and did a billion iterations, I should not expect to leak memory. Everything I insert, will be deleted. A memory check shows this behaviour.

Now consider I use a vector of pointers (to objects on the heap) ...

```
std::vector<int*> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int * myIntP = new int(5);
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

In this case, only the pointer itself ought to be removed each time pop_back() is called, and the underlying object remains un-deleted, causing a memory leak. So after a billion iterations I have quite some significant memory being used, even though I have no entries in my vector.

Now what if I have a vector of pointers (to objects on the stack) ...

```
std::vector<int*> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int myInt = 5;
    int * myIntP = &myInt;
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

Here the pointers point to stack objects. Is their memory freed in the call to pop_back(), or not? A memory check showed me that this behaviour was no memory leaked. The small amount of memory used, indicated that this behaved like objects on the stack. However this was not expected to me, because if the pointer had been passed into me from another function, to a stack variable i.e.

```
void myFunc(int * myIntP)
{
    std::vector<int*> myVec;
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
int main()
{
    int myInt = 5;                                                                                                                      
    int * myIntP = &myInt;
    myFunc(myIntP);
    std::cout << (*myIntP) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then allowing the vector to free this memory, would render my myIntP pointing to removed data. So surely this can't be correct?

Could anyone help explain?

Also is there a name for "a pointer pointing to a variable on the stack" i.e. not initialised with "new"?

Thanks

Joey

Comment: a `vector` only stores your structure. If your structure is a pointer, the vector does not check that it is valid and does not free the memory it points to. When you allocate dynamically you might want to use smart pointers, whose destructors free allocated memory.

Comment: Type notwithstanding, a vector doesn't know or care what a pointer points to. When you remove one from the vector it deletes the memory the pointer occupied but *never* deletes the thing it was pointing to, whether that object be on the stack or on the heap.

Answer (score 6):

```
while(true)
{
    int myInt = 5;
    int * myIntP = &myInt;
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

You only actually have one int here, `myInt` with a value of 5. The loop will re-use the same one. You push a pointer to that one int into the vector and then remove it. Nothing else is happening. There isn't a memory leak because you are not allocating new ints.

STD containers do *nothing different* for pointers than they would for a 32/64 bit interger. As far as they care, a pointer is just another number. So, if you insert a pointer into a container, it is *your responsibility* to delete it.

Comment: Not really what it is doing, nothing is reused(not withstanding unseen optimizations). This piece of code starting with `while(){` creates new stack frame and in that frame creates an int and then a pointer to the int. Then a copy of the pointer is added to a vector,(the vector's array is on the heap) then it deletes the item from the vector. Now at the end of the while `}` the whole stack frame is popped off with everything inside. For this to create a leak it would need to make the int pointer first and `new` the int on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a pointer to a variable on the stack, the variable will be destructed when it goes out of scope, regardless of the pointer. And destructing the pointer (as long as you don't call delete on it) will have no effect on the variable.

So if you stop using your pointer before, no problem, if you store it longer, problem...

And if you plan on using pointers on dynamically allocated variable, you should look into smart pointers.

Comment: So if you stop using your pointer before [the object goes out of scope], no problem, if you store it longer, problem... I understand this, but if I want my while loop to execute indefinitely, but don't want a load of redundant objects in memory (i.e. I know I'm done with them, when I call pop_back()). How can I ensure this?

Comment: Either don't use a pointer, or use smart pointers that ensures you the allocated memory will be deleted when the pointer is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

> Here the pointers point to stack objects. Is their memory freed in the call to pop_back(), or not?

No, they are not. They are freed when they go out of scope, which happens at the `}`. After the `}`, the memory is no longer used for this variable (the stack-frame popped off) and will be reused! So if you didn't pop-off the pointer right after pushing it, your vector would contain a dangling pointer when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Okay, but if I want this while loop to execute forever, the stack objects will never go out of scope. However I still want to remove them from memory. How can I take care of this myself?

Comment: The stack-frame _will_ go out of scope. When I say, it goes out of scope at the `}` doesn't this only mean when the while-loop ends but after __every__ iteration.

Comment: Ah okay. That's what I didn't understand. So then the ONLY reason I'd have objects occupying memory after their pointers had been popped, is if I had declared the pointers with "new" and had not also called "delete"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Stackspace (local variables, essentially everything not created with `new`) are automatically freed when the scope where they were created in ends.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's go through each of your examples:

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int myInt = 5;
    myVec.push_back(myInt);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

The push_back() method makes a *copy of the argument* and stores the copy internally.  So, if you were storing an stack-allocated object instead of a primitive, a copy constructor would have been called. The pop_back() method does not assume anything either.  It removes the *copy of the item* you stored (whether it was a value or a pointer) and removes it from its internal storage. If the copy stored was a stack-allocated object, the class' destructor will be called when the container manages its internal memory because the copy item will no longer be in scope.

Your second example:

```
std::vector<int*> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int * myIntP = new int(5);
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

As you stated, the integer is allocated on the heap.  Calling push_back() still stores the argument. In this case, you are not storing the value of the integer "5", the value of the *pointer*, an address of a memory location that contains the value of "5". Since you allocated the memory that stores the "5", you are responsible for getting that pointer and deallocate the memory. The pop_back() method does not delete the pointer for you nor returns you a copy of the pointer.

Your third example has subtle differences:

```
std::vector<int*> myVec;
while(true)
{
    int myInt = 5;
    int * myIntP = &myInt;
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
```

In this case, you are not allocating any memory on the heap. You assigning the address of myInt, which is a stack-allocated value, to a pointer. Stack memory lives through out the life of a process and does not deallocate on its own. However, once you leave the current scope (the while loop), the memory reused by something else. The memory is still there, but it may no longer have the value you expect.

Your last example:

```
void myFunc(int * myIntP)
{
    std::vector<int*> myVec;
    myVec.push_back(myIntP);
    myVec.pop_back();
}
int main()
{
    int myInt = 5;                                                                                                                      
    int * myIntP = &myInt;
    myFunc(myIntP);
    std::cout << (*myIntP) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You were expected the memory for myInt to be dealloated after making myFunc() was called.  However, container methods do not modify the supplied values. They copy them.  When myFunc() pushed the myIntP pointer, it is pushing the *pointer*, the address of what myIntP points to, not the value in memory of that address. You would have to dereference the pointer, using call:

```
myVec.push_back(*myIntP);
```

Note that even if you did this, containers copy the value. So, myInt is still unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing and conflating "destruction" and "deletion" -- they are **NOT** the same thing, but are two different concepts in C++.

Deletion can *only* happen with pointers -- if you try to delete a non-pointer, you'll get a compile-time error.  Deletion first destroys the pointed at object and then returns the memory for it to the heap.

Destruction on the other hand can happen with anything, but is mostly only of interest with classes, where it calls the destructor.  With any type that has no destructor (such as `int` or any raw pointer type), destruction does nothing.  While you CAN destroy an object manually, you pretty much never do -- it happens automatically for you when something else happens.  For example, when a local variable goes out of scope, it is destroyed.

So in your code above, what happens?  Well you have a local `std::vector` which is destroyed when it goes out of scope.  Its destructor will delete anything it allocated internally, and destroy all the elements of the vector.  It will NOT however, delete any elements of the vector.  When you have `vector<int>`, that's all there is, since nothing else was allocated, but when you have a `vector<int *>`, if those pointers were allocated, they'll leak.  If they weren't allocated (if they point at locals), there's nothing to leak.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn deep the scope variable validity 
exemple :

```
 {
  int myVar;//Construct myVar on the stack
 }//At this point, myVar is deleted with the stack
```

in your last exemple, you declare myInt at the start of main and don't do anything on value in myFunc.

It's normal to don't lose myInt data. it will be erase after the return 0;